Non normal data in a LMM; beginners question
I am new to statistics and am seeking guidance on analyzing the effects of earthworms on litter-derived carbon using R.
I conducted an experiment to assess the impact of earthworm presence (with three levels: no worms, some worms, many worms) and soil type (with four levels: wheat, maize, pumpkin, and strawberry grown soil) on litter carbon formation across two time intervals (three months and five months).
This results in a total of
3 (worms) × 4 (crops) × 2 (time) = 24 treatments
For the first time interval, I have 2 replicates per treatment; for the second interval, I have 3 replicates per treatment.
I constructed the following linear mixed model in R:
lmm_model1 <- lmer(Litter_derived_total_C ~ worms + (1 | Crop) + (1 | time), data = dataCN)

The QQ plot of the residuals shows non-normality (Fig1). A log transformation somewhat improved the data in terms of equal variances between groups. However, residual normality remains a concern (Fig 2).
Question:
Given that the residuals are not normally distributed, how should I proceed with my analysis? Are there alternative models or transformations you would recommend to address the normality issue? Any advice on model diagnostics or improvements would also be appreciated.
Fig1

Fig2


There are several things you could try. There are nonlinear MLMs, or you could try adding a spline of worms. Probably other things too.

It is unclear why you want to fit a linear mixed model to this data. The number of levels for crop and time seems very low to support random effects. Also, why do you want to include time as a random grouping factor? Do you expect measurements from different worms to be correlated at the same time point?
Regarding the distribution of the error terms, you may want to try a Student's t distribution.

First of, random effects need a lot of groups. You don't have that so mixed models (without priors) are inappropriate.  https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random

in case ns<10 it is safer to use the variable as a fixed effect.

Now normality of residuals is generally the least important aspect of a linear regression (Andrew Gelman https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2013/08/04/19470/):


Validity. Most importantly, the data you are analyzing should map to the research question you are trying to answer. This sounds obvious but is often overlooked or ignored because it can be inconvenient. . . .
Additivity and linearity. The most important mathematical assumption of the regression model is that its deterministic component is a linear function of the separate predictors . . .
Independence of errors. . . .
Equal variance of errors. . . .
Normality of errors. . . .



Further assumptions are necessary if a regression coefficient is to be given a causal interpretation . . .
Normality and equal variance are typically minor concerns, unless you’re using the model to make predictions for individual data points.

In general I'd report it as a minor limitation of the analysis. More discusion here: Why is the normality of residuals "barely important at all" for the purpose of estimating the regression line?
However, your non normality in the log model comes from one outlier (-1.5). Don't remove it, but do try to find out what is up with that observation.
Further make sure you understand point 2. There is some ambiguity in your question whether you understand the difference between worms + Crop and worms * Crop.
Ultimately plot your data and model together. I've set something up with a different dataset that you should be able to adjust well for your own:

library(palmerpenguins)
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)

penguins = na.omit(palmerpenguins::penguins) %>% mutate(year = ordered(year))

mod_lm <- lm(bill_length_mm ~ year + sex + island, data = penguins) 
penguins$mod_pred <- predict(mod_lm)
mod_dat <- penguins %>%  select(year, sex, island, mod_pred) %>% distinct()

ggplot(penguins, aes(x = year, y = bill_length_mm, color = sex)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.1, height = 0) +
  facet_wrap(~island, nrow = 1) +
  geom_point(data = mod_dat, aes(y = mod_pred), size = 5, shape = 23) +
  geom_path(data = mod_dat, aes(y = mod_pred, group = sex)) +
  theme_bw()


